# add a line between matching pattern - unix

Tags: awk, sed

I want to insert "123" below madguy-xyz- line in "module xyz".
There are multiple modules having similar lines. But i want to add it in only "module xyz".

```
module abc 
    njkenjkfvsfd
    madguy-xyz-mafdvnskjfvn
    enfvjkesn
endmodule

module xyz
    njkenjkfvsfd
    madguy-xyz-mafdvnskjfvn
    enfvjkesn
endmodule
```

This is the code i tried but doesn't work,

```
sed -i "/module xyz/,/^endmodule/{/madguy-xyz-/a 123}" <file_name>
```

This is the error I got:
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'

Comment: Insert a newline before `}`.

Comment: You have multiple answers that will fail if `module xyzabc` existed or `module xyz` didn't contain `mdguy-zyz-` but a subsequent module did or it contained `foo-madguy-xyz` or it contained regexp metachars like `.` or various other cases not covered by the example in your question. It's always trivial to match the text you want but much harder to not match similar text that you don't want matched so when posting a question it's worth putting some effort into creating an example that includes as many of the rainy day cases as you can think of rather than just the 1 sunny-day case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed I suggest:

```
sed -i -e "/module xyz/,/^endmodule/{/madguy-xyz-/a 123" -e "}"  file
```

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/module xyz/{:a;n;/madguy-xyz-/!ba;p;s/\S.*/123/}' file
```

For a line containing `module xyz`, continue printing lines until one containing `madguy-xyz-`.

Print this line too and then replace it with `123`.

Another alternative solution:

```
sed '/module/h;G;/madguy-xyz.*\nmodule xyz/{P;s/\S.*/123/};P;d' file
```

Store any module line in the hold space.

Append the module line to each line.

If the first line contains `madguy-xyz-` and the second `module xyz`, print the first then substitute the second for `123`.

Print the first line and delete the whole.

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
awk '1; /^endmodule$/{found=""};/^module xyz$/{found=1} found && /^ +madguy-xyz-/{print "123"} ' Input_file
```

Once you are happy with results of above command, to save output into Input_file itself try following then:

```
awk '1;/^endmodule$/{found=""} /^module xyz$/{found=1} found && /^ +madguy-xyz-/{print "123"} ' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                      ##Starting awk program from here.
1;
/^endmodule$/{found=""}    ##Printing current line here.
/^module xyz$/{            ##Checking condition if line contains module xyz then do following.
  found=1                  ##Setting found to 1 here.
}
found && /^ +madguy-xyz-/{   ##Checking if found is SET and line contains madguy-xyz- then do following.
  print "123"              ##Printing 123 here.
}
' Input_file               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***NOTE:*** In case your line exactly having `module xyz` value then change above `/module xyz/` (this condition) to `$0=="module xyz"` too.

Answer (score 2):

Using any POSIX awk in any shell on every Unix box, the following will work for the sunny day case in your question and all rainy day cases such as the ones I mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67135214/add-a-line-between-matching-pattern-unix/67137881#comment118672495_67135214) and more:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ print }

$1 == "endmodule" {
    inMod = 0
}

inMod && (index($1,old) == 1) {
    sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"")
    print $0 new
}

($1 == "module") && ($2 == mod) {
    inMod = 1
}
```

```
$ awk -v mod='xyz' -v old='madguy-xyz-' -v new='123' -f tst.awk file
module abc
    njkenjkfvsfd
    madguy-xyz-mafdvnskjfvn
    enfvjkesn
endmodule

module xyz
    njkenjkfvsfd
    madguy-xyz-mafdvnskjfvn
    123
    enfvjkesn
endmodule
```